# Sails.js Populate Issue

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am having an issues getting .populate to work in Sails.  If I use the below models and I use .populateAll then it works and I get an association and some data, but I also get two sails generated functions tacked on.  I just want to be able to get a school record from the database and all reviews associated with that school.  If I use .populate(), I get the error:

**Error: Encountered unexpected error while building join instructions for `.populate("Reviews")`**

Any help would be fantastic!

Schools.js Model

```
module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  tableName:'schools',
  attributes: {
    SID: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      size: 15
    },
    schoolName: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolCity: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolCountry: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolRegion: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolWebsite: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolCountryCode: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolNumbStudents: {
      type: 'integer',
    },
    schoolNumbFaculty: {
      type: 'integer',
      size: 4,
      defaultsTo: '0'
    },
    schoolCurriculum: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolLanguage: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolLangInstruction: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolonetoone: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolAccred: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolRatio: {
      type: 'string',
      size: 3
    },
    schoolMission: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolFiveWords: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolInitiatives: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMin: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMax: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryBA: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryBAPlus: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMA: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolSalaryMAPlus: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolHealth: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolAirfare: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolAirfareProv: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolHousing: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolDependent: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolShipping: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolRetirement: {
      type: 'text',
    },
    schoolreviews: {
        collection: 'Reviews',
        via: 'schoolID',
        dominant: true
    }
  }
};
```

Reviews.js Model

```
module.exports = {
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  tableName:'reviews',
  attributes: {
    RID: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      size: 15
    },
    schoolID: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 15,
      model:'Schools'
    },
    profileID: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 15
    },
    active: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 1
    },
    dateCreated: {
      type: 'date',
      required: true,
      defaultsTo: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    },
    Q1: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q2: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q3: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q4: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q5: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q6: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q7: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q8: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q9: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q10: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q11: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q12: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q13: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q14: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q15: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q16: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q17: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q18: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q19: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q20: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q21: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q22: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q23: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q24: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q25: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q26: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q27: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q28: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q29: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q30: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q31: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q32: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q33: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q34: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q35: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q36: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q37: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q38: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q39: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q40: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q41: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q42: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q43: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q44: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q45: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q46: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q47: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q48: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q49: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q50: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q51: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    Q52: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 2
    },
    freeReview: {
      type: 'text',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

ReviewsController.js

```
module.exports = {
  reviews: function(req, res){
    Schools.findOne(1)
      .populate('reviews')
      .exec(function afterFind(err, theresults) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        return res.view({thereviews: theresults});
    });
  },
  schoolreviews: function(req, res){
    Reviews.find()
      .exec(function afterFind(err, theresults) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        return res.view({thereviews: theresults});
    });
  },
  testsearch: function(req, res){
    Schools.findOne(1).populate('Reviews').exec(function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming schools --> reviews is a 1 to many relationship. Your model setups are incorrect. If you want to query schools and .populate reviews data for each school then you need to add reviews as a collection on the Schools model like this:

```
reviews: {
  collection: 'reviews',
  via: 'school'
}
```

Note: the collection attribute is the lowercase model name.

Then in the Reviews model, replace your SchoolID attribute with a reference to the Schools model. This will allow you to return school data when you do a query on Reviews - for example: Reviews.find(...).populate('school')

```
school: {
  required: true,
  model: 'schools'
}
```

Note: when you do a find() for Reviews **without** .populate() the school attribute will be the _id of the school record.